# What is the Blink-182 song that The Chainsmokers beat to death in Tuscon?

Tags: identify-this-song, lyrics

In the song ["Closer"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PT2_F-1esPk) by [The Chainsmokers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chainsmokers) they mention another song by [Blink-182](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink-182). The lyrics go:

> Play that Blink-182 song
>   That we beat to death in Tuscon

Is there any way of knowing which song this is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the duo's annotations on that line on Genius.com](http://genius.com/10162921), they're talking about "[I Miss You](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1tAYmMjLdY)".

Andrew Taggart's annotation:

> We were listening to Blink-182’s “I Miss You” and had just started playing it in our sets when we wrote this song. A lot of the inspiration for the song writing comes from bands like Blink-182 and Taking Back Sunday.

Alex Pall's annotation:

> We had been playing “I Miss You” in our sets a lot at the time and Blink was on our minds a lot so that’s where that idea came from. Blink also played a large role in our musical history growing up. As for “Tucson,” it just rhymed and also touches on the geographical special references we use in the song.